# how to achieve more complicated dag scheduling with airflow?

Tags: airflow

Airflow makes it easy to run jobs at fixed intervals.  This post seeks advice on how to handle a more complicated scheduling requirement.

For example, suppose I have process that pulls files from SFTP server and does something with them.  The source only posts files M-F.  I want the dag to behave the following way:

- run only M-F;
- on Mondays, look for file from `execution_date - 0` and `- 1` and `- 2`
- Tue-Fri,  just look for `execution date - 0`?

It seems this is not practical to implement, and what I need to do is just design it to pull whatever files happen to be there and run every day, without reference to specific files.

The thing is, if I can specify files driven by `execution_date` then I can see exactly what has been pulled and hasn’t and make use of retry functionality.

One way that comes to mind is create 7 dags each with weekly schedule.   But I do not like that idea.

Another case would be if I wanted a process to run every second sunday of the month.  Is there any way to do this kind of thing?

EDIT: 
I  think cleanest way to achieve this will be to design the dag to always pull files with date `execution_date`, but to just not trigger the sat and sun runs until monday (and to use trigger dag operator to do so), and to use a controller dag with BranchOperator and TriggerDagOperator to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zack's answer was helpful in solving this (because branch operator was necessary) but the solution I am going with is to use `TriggerDagRunOperator`.

Here are the dags I built in order to test this approach.

**Target dag**

```
def alert(ti, **kwargs):
    message = f"Execution date is {ti.execution_date}"
    print(message)

with target_dag:
    PythonOperator(
        python_callable=alert,
        task_id='target_task',
        provide_context=True,
    )
```

**Trigger dag**

```
def check_day(ti, **kwargs):
    execution_date = ti.execution_date
    if execution_date.minute % 7 == 0:
        return ['weekday_trigger', 'saturday_trigger', 'sunday_trigger']
    elif execution_date.minute % 7 in range(1, 5):
        return ['weekday_trigger']
    else:
        return []

with trigger_dag:
    check_day_task = BranchPythonOperator(
        task_id='check_day_task',
        python_callable=check_day,
        provide_context=True,
    )

    weekday_trigger = TriggerDagRunOperator(
        task_id='weekday_trigger',
        trigger_dag_id='target_dag',
        execution_date='{{ execution_date }}'
    )
    saturday_trigger = TriggerDagRunOperator(
        task_id='saturday_trigger',
        trigger_dag_id='target_dag',
        execution_date='{{ execution_date + macros.timedelta(days=-1) }}'
    )
    sunday_trigger = TriggerDagRunOperator(
        task_id='sunday_trigger',
        trigger_dag_id='target_dag',
        execution_date='{{ execution_date + macros.timedelta(days=-2) }}'
    )

    check_day_task >> [weekday_trigger, saturday_trigger, sunday_trigger]
```

**Why not just use branch operator?**

The reason I prefer this approach is that my target dag doesn't need to care about the complicated scheduling.  All it needs to care about is the execution date.  It so happens that on Mondays we want to execute `execution_date - 1` and `execution_date - 2` in addition to `execution_date`.  But the target dag operates the same way no matter what: it does a specific thing, based on `execution_date`.

If I try to incorporate branch operator into the target dag, it gets messy very quickly.  E.g. if your target dag has 4 tasks, then you need to duplicate those 2x on mondays.  Additionally, the tree view of dag run history would be ugly, with a lot of skipped tasks and backfill would probably be weird.

**Wrapup**

So, on non-monday weekdays, our trigger dag triggers `target_dag` with same execution date as trigger dag.  On the weekend, the trigger dag doesn't trigger anything.   And on mondays, it executes 3 runs of `target_dag`, for monday and the prior two days.

Note: I used minutes to simulate days in testing scheduled runs.

Here's the graph view off trigger_dag dag:
[image: graph view of trigger dag]

The tree view of the main task remains clean and simple:
[image: tree view of target dag]

Comment: This was a very nice wrap up post. I was having some trouble understanding your answer to my comment above, but I can understand your logic now. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Set the DAG's `'schedule_interval':` to be  `'0 0 * * 1-5'` runs at 00:00 on every day-of-week from Monday through Friday. Adjust the time as needed ( first two zeroes).

Next, use `BranchPythonOperator` as a way of entry for the DAG. So on Mondays, the DAG is executed and looks for file with `execution_date - 0`, `execution_date - 1`, and `execution_date - 2`. Tuesdays to Fridays, it just looks for `execution_date - 0`.

I created a quick example to show you what I mean. I hope it's a sufficient example. Let me know if I can help out further.

```
#Airflow imports
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
from airflow.operators.python_operator import BranchPythonOperator
# General imports
from datetime import datetime

DAG_ID = 'stackoverflow_exampledag'

args = {
    'owner': 'you',
    'email': ['you@yourwork.com'],
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'email_on_failure': True,
    'start_date': datetime(2019, 4, 14)
}

dag = DAG(
    dag_id=DAG_ID,
    default_args=args,
    schedule_interval="0 0 * * 1-5"
    )


#################################
######## Python Script ##########
#################################


def checktheday(**kwargs):
    weekday = datetime.today().weekday()
    if weekday == 1:
        return 'monday_only_task'
    else:
        return 'tuesday_through_friday_task'


####################################
########## TASKS ###################
####################################

# BranchPythonOperator is the entry point for this DAG.
# The python callable will return the task id of the appriorate subdag/task that it's supposed to run.

checktheday_task = BranchPythonOperator(
    task_id='checktheday_task',
    python_callable=checktheday,
    dag=dag,
    provide_context=True
    )

monday_only_task = DummyOperator(
    task_id='monday_only_task',
    dag=dag
    )

tuesday_through_friday_task = DummyOperator(
    task_id='tuesday_through_friday_task',
    dag=dag


#################################
########## ORCHESTRATION ########
#################################
monday_only_task.set_upstream(checktheday_task)
tuesday_through_friday_task.set_upstream(checktheday_task)
```

[image: example graph view]

Comment: I am currently thinking the cleanest way to implement this is to use trigger dag operator, so that the dag _always_ looks for file with date `execution_date` and the control dag just doesn't schedule sat and sun runs until monday

Comment: @chorbs I'm not sure I understand. Why use TriggerDagOperator? The BranchPythonOperator will accomplish everything that I think you are trying to do. You can just add onto the monday_only_task  to process Saturday / Sunday runs as well.

Comment: The problem is that each day I pull 4 types of file for that date and i would like each to be its own task instance.  Consequently, with this approach, my dag would have 12 ti's in each dag run, and 8 of them would be skipped daily, and all of them would be skipped on weekends.  It's just messy when thinking about tree view.  With trigger dag approach, the tree view is clean and shows history neatly, not muddied by the idiosyncratic scheduling required.